# Facebook Login with "Facebook Unity SDK (4.3.3)" and Friends Smash on Android device

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine

I'm testing the Facebook Unity SDK with the example app "Friend Smash".

I've followed the video tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5g0WdYbq-dg

I build the game on my Android Device. I launch the app and when I click on the "Login with Facebook" and authorise the access to my profil, friends etc... It comes back to the "Friends Smash" home screen and nothing appears.

I checked out the Android Log and there is this error  :

"Java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)&access_token=&"

My Unity 3D Version : 4.2.1f4
 - Facebook Unity SDK : 4.3.3
- Android : JellyBean 4.2.2

I need help :( Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem logging in with android, though I didn't check the log for errors.

I solved it by adding the Android platform in the Facebook app settings (in developer.facebook.com), and then pasting the values for "Package Name", "Class Name" and "Key Hashes". The values are present in Facebook settings in the Unity Editor.